# Snowflake connector issues with it being recognized as a module on Jupyter but not on Spyder

Tags: python, anaconda, spyder, modulenotfounderror, snowflake-connector

So while using Spyder on Windows, I tried to run import snowflake.connector and intially, it would give me a module not found error. I knew the connector was installed via pip, so this time I tried to install it via Anaconda.

Now when I run import snowflake.connector, it gives me the error "No module named 'snowflake.connector', snowflake is not a package"

However, if I run this in Jupyter notebook it runs fine without error. I have tried changing the PYTHONPATH on spyder to no avail (unless I did it wrong), I also even tried changing the interpreter location so I am at a loss.

Any help is resolving this issue would be appreciated, I am trying to move away from Jupyter Notebook

Comment: Did you restart you console kernel after installing the package and setting the custom interpreter preference?